# 404 Errors on WCF service hosted in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I am trying to create a WCF service hostsed in windows service and I'm testing locally before I deploy to a server.

Created and installed the service ok and I can run the service just fine.

When I try to add a reference either though Visual studio or using WCFTestClient I get the following error.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error URI: http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service     Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:'
>   http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service'. There was no endpoint
>   listening at http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service that could
>   accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or
>   SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.     The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. HTTP GET Error
>   URI: http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service    There was an
>   error downloading 'http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service'.
>   The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.

here is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CalculatorServiceBehavior" name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />        
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CalculatorServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>        
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

As you can see its a slight modification to the tutorial found on msdn for hosting a WCF service in a Windows Service.

I have tried reaserching this but haven't found much or most of the issues seem related to IIS hosting.

UPDATE

After adding the port number as suggested by venerik, the error has now changed to the following.

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.    There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.    Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service'.    Unable to connect to the remote server    No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Your path should be `http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service.svc` when adding reference.

Comment: @MairajAhmad Just tried, still generates an error

Comment: what is name of your class .I guess it is `CalculatorService` if this is the name than address should be `http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/CalculatorService.svc`

Comment: @MairajAhmad class name is CalculatorWindowsService, tried replacing /service with /CalculatorWindowsService and it still generate the error

Comment: Ok browse the service by right clicking on svc file and click browse and use that path.

Comment: There is no svc file?

Comment: Did you install and start the windows service as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069(v=vs.110).aspx Be sure to run the command prompt as an administrator.

Comment: no I added a Setup Project to do the installing because I was deploying this onto a server. Couldn't get service working and thought I was trying to run before walking so tried to get it working locally first. But as I say, the service is installed and running.

Comment: Well, that's weird. Your config says your service should be listening at 8000  but that error says nothing is listening at that port. I'd double check whether the windows service is properly installed and running (through Control Panel for instance).

Comment: Just had another check, installed and is running

Comment: In what way is your service different from the tutorial? I just followed the tutorial step by step and everything works like a charm.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. The ServiceName was not set in the service properties so I set this and also ensured the installer matched. Also set it to a LocalSystem Account. Not sure if that had any affect but it was NetworkService

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your client (like WcfTestClient) to `http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service`. The error says you are trying to connect to `http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service` without the port, that is.

I assume you have IIS running at localhost? That's why the error also says `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.` The IIS server is listening at port 80 and cannot find `ServiceModelSamples/service` and thus returns 404.

Comment: Tried adding the port and I still get an error, although its no longer a 404 error. Also this is not running in IIS, its a windows service hosted.

Comment: I didn't say the service is running in IIS but I assume your computer does run IIS. The client tries to get 'http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service'. Since IIS is listening on localhost (port 80) IIS is trying to service the request. Anyway, could you update the question with the new error?

Comment: So I still need IIS to run even though I'm hosting in a windows service?

Comment: No, you don't. The point is: your machine is probably running IIS as well as your windows service. IIS listens at port 80 for HTTP-requests. Your windows service is listening at port 8000 for HTTP-request. A request like 'http://localhost/ServiceModelSamples/service' is directed to port 80 (the default port for HTTP-requests) and thus serviced by IIS A request like 'http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelsSamples/service' is directed to port 8000. The port your windows service should be listening (according to your app.config).

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was the Service Name was not set in the service properties so I set this and also ensured the installer service name matched.
Also set it to a `LocalSystem` Account. Not sure if that had any affect but it was set as `NetworkService`